# How do I list all files that have a vowel as the second character in its name

Tags: shell, unix, wildcard

I created an alias `ll="ls -laF"` and i have tried to use `ll *[aeiou] [aeiou]*`
and it just shows all the files that have two two files that have the letters aeiou in them. I also tried `ll *[aeiou]*` and i just get a listing of everything in a file again.

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: a list of all the files that have a vowel as the second character.so say there was a directory with the words (like,the,cat,dog,great) only (like cat dog) should show up

Comment: Then your problem is that `*` doesn't do what you want.  You're looking for `?[aeiou]*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ? matches a single character, so you're looking for
`ls -laF ?[aeiou]*`